# How to programmatically save a block's title?

Tags: 7, blocks

Nice Menus is a custom block module that was created by another devleoper and I am trying to go in programmatically and change the title to `"<none>"` with this code:

```
function nice_menus_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if ($data['content']['module']['#value'] == 'nice_menus'){
    $data['content']['settings']['title']['#value'] = "<none>";
  }
}
```

Here is the issue I am running into. If I am on the block configuration page, it does display the text `"<none>"` on the title-field, but it does NOT insert this data into the database. Only ***AFTER*** I hit save, does it record `"<none>"` into it. Here is a screenshot example:

[image]

As you can see on Nice Menus 2, that is the one I clicked "save" and it set it to the database. However, my code is suppose to set `"<none>"` to both nice_menus 1 and 2. I do not want to have the user click "save", but rather have it already set with my code. How does one go about "saving" their changes in my function? I already have other fields saved on this block by using the variable_set function, but the title field is restricted to the official block_module.

Comment: If you're overriding the output unconditionally, why do you need to update the database? If you want to make sure no one can edit it once you've set it to `<none>`, a `hook_form_alter` to set the field to `#disabled` or a `#type` of `value` might make more sense, or if you want people to be able to edit it but then nuke them on submit, add some validation logic to the form which changes it back. In an alter hook for a view changes wouldn't persist - the changes you're making are to a render array meant for a template

Comment: Its not that I don't want people to change or edit it, but the problem I"m having is the menu title is showing up on navigation because title is not set to "none". The string text "none" shows up when i go to the module configuration page, but its only for show. Only if I hit submit / save does "none" get pushed and inserted into the database, and then the title disappears.